# Setting the default value of the slider for datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails application I have a simple datetimepicker for selecting start and the end dates with respective input labels (Please find the attached screenshot initial.png).
Upon clicking the input fields the calendar pop up comes out along with a slider which allows me to set the time (which is initially set to 10, which is the minimum value). But I need to set the default value of the end date to the maximum value (which is 19 in my case) as soon as I click on it. (Please find the attached screenshot expected.png)

Here is my code, in the Rails app

`default.js` file

```
 $(".leave-date").datetimepicker({
    showMinute:false,
    hourMin: 10,
    hourMax: 19,
  });
```

Can anybody please help me to achieve this[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".leave-date").datetimepicker({ 
showMinute:false,
 hourMin: 10,
 hourMax: 19,
 hour: 19,
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass parameter `hour` at the time of initialization like this :

```
$(".leave-date").datetimepicker({ showMinute:false, hour: 19, hourMin: 10, hourMax: 19, });
```

For more options you can go though this [link](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-options)